# Java-decrypted file ruined

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

I have a program that has to encrypt an audio file and then decrypt it if needed. I tested my program on some other types of files, like .bin or .txt. The problem I get is that the decrypted file has some weird characters before the actual content, like the source file contains "010101" and after encryption-decryption it has "¬íw0w 010101".

My encryption method code goes here:

```
public void cipherTheAudioFile(String fileDir, String fileToCipher) throws            FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException,  InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    File audioSourceFile = new File(fileDir + "\\" + fileToCipher);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
            new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/encrypted/" + fileToCipher + ".sky"), cipher));

    byte[] audioFileInBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(audioSourceFile);
    oos.write(audioFileInBytes);

    fos = new FileOutputStream(KEY_FILE);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
    DESKeySpec keyspec = (DESKeySpec) skf.getKeySpec(key, DESKeySpec.class);
    fos.write(keyspec.getKey());

    fos.close();
    oos.close();
}
```

My decryption method code goes here:

```
public void decryptTheAudioFile(String fileDir, String fileToDecipher) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException {
    fis = new FileInputStream(keyFile);
    byte[] keyspecbytes = new byte[fis.available()];

    File fileToWriteIn = createFileToWriteIn(fileDir, fileToDecipher);

    fis.read(keyspecbytes);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithm);
    DESKeySpec keyspec = new DESKeySpec(keyspecbytes);
    SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret(keyspec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
        new CipherInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/encrypted/" + fileToDecipher + ".sky"), cipher));
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileToWriteIn));

    byte[] audioFileInBytes = new byte[1024];

    int numRead = 0;
    while ((numRead = ois.read(audioFileInBytes)) >= 0) {
        oos.write(audioFileInBytes, 0, numRead);
    }

    oos.close();
    fis.close();
    ois.close();
}
```

P.S. It could be something with the encoding, but I am not really sure.

EDITED

Ok, I have changed to the FileWriters, but still no change. Here goes the code:

```
 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/encrypted/" + fileToCipher + ".sky");
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(audioSourceFile), cipher);
    byte[] audioFileInBytes = new byte[1024];
    int numRead = 0;
    while ((numRead = cis.read(audioFileInBytes)) >= 0) {
            os.write(audioFileInBytes, 0, numRead);
    }
```

Likewise goes the decryptor.

Comment: If you suspect encoding might be the cause, then in case of text files it might be that the input file is UTF-8 with BOM and the output UTF-8 without BOM. Wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): Many Windows programs (including Windows Notepad) add the bytes 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF at the start of any document saved as UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it on .txt files, but my actual task is aimed towards .mp3 When I decrypt the .mp3 file I receive something that sounds more like dubstep, but not the actual audio file. :)

Comment: Some people like dubstep. For them, this might be a valid encryption/decryption chain. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way that the `decryptTheAudioFile` method writes the file.  Specifically, the problem is that it is using an `ObjectOutputStream`.  That is adding an object serialization header.  But it doesn't belong there at all.

The solution is to get rid of this from `decryptTheAudioFile`:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
         new FileOutputStream(fileToWriteIn));
```

and replace it with this:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileToWriteIn);
```

and change the rest of the code to write to `os`.  Your code needs to mirror how you are reading the file in `cipherTheAudioFile`.

---

It would be a good idea to get rid of the other `ObjectStream` instances too and simply read and write to plain `Streams`.  The other `ObjectStream`s are harmless (mostly), but they don't actually achieve anything.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just tried it, but still getting the same stuff. :(

Comment: Did you change the final one like I said?  Because that is where the real problem is.

Comment: Well, I did. It all reads from the CipherInputStream (it processes the pointed file) and writes to os. In the encryptor I read from the source file and write to the encrypted one; in the decryptor I read from the encrypted and write to the new file.

Comment: Yes! It was my small typo.. Thank you so much! It made it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Drop all the ObjectOutputStreams and ObjectInputStreams. You are writing a byte array so they are unnecessary. The extra bytes you see are probably telling you the type and size of the byte[].

Comment: Do you mean that I should use simple I/O streams, but not the object ones?

Comment: When you write something other than a byte[] you might need them but not here.